# Javascript DropDown from the DB

Tags: java, javascript

Please am using this Javascript Script to pull rows from my Exam table. And what is pulled from the Exam table should as well pull the subject table. Below are things I have tried using Javascript and Java.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selRow(){document.getElementById('ExamId').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('SubjectId').selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
}}</script>
```

So my intentional on this whole thing is that when the user selects ExamId let it pull SubjectId belonging to Exam as Subject has ExamFK in my database.

This is my code for ExamID pull from the database:

```
<td width="121"><select name="txtExam" id="ExamId" onChange="selRow()">
<option value="">[Select an Exam First]</option>
<%if (exams != null && !exams.isEmpty()){
for (Iterator iterator = exams.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
Exam exam = (Exam)iterator.next();%>
<option value="<%= exam.getId()%>"><%= exam.getName()%></option>
<%}}%></select></td>
```

And this is my code to make the subsequent changes from the Subject Table:

```
<td width="130"> <select name="txtSubject" id="SubjectId">
<option value="0">[Select Subject]</option>
<%Long l = new Long(0L); 
if (subjects != null && !subjects.isEmpty()){
// instance.setSelectedExamId(Long.valueOf(subjectIdString));
// exams = (Exam)exams.getRecordById(Exam.class, Long.valueOf(subjectIdString));
for (Iterator iterator = exams.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
Exam exam = (Exam)iterator.next();

Subject subject;

subject = (Subject)ExamPrepValidationServlet.examService.getRecordById(Exam.class, l);
%><option value="<%= subject.getId()%>"><%= subject.getName()%></option>
<%}}%> 
</select></td>
```

I don't know if I am in the right direction, but please someone should come to my aid.
Thanks

Comment: @Patrick Ndu It looks alright so far. I assume you are reloading the entire page after Subject is selected?

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Yeah, My problem now is that when Exam is loaded, let it pull Subject based on ExamFK found in Subject Table and the above code is not performing the intended purpose despite hours of research I have placed into this.

Comment: It would help if you said exactly what it *is* doing at the moment.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: At the moment when the Exam combo is selected the Subject combo is not pulling in respect to the Exam Ids in the Subject table